# How do deal with special characters in Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, bot-framework-composer, power-virtual-agents

How do I remove all special characters before sending it through a HTTP request in Bot Framework Composer? I can't find a way to 'sanitise' the text via adaptive expressions. If it helps, I created the chatbot through Power Virtual Agents.

Answer (score 0):

In Bot composer, you can use custom actions and implement your own logic.
here the steps for [custom action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZJRtyYP0hY&list=PL-PgMmMmma8D5WRvwKhzQrEEM5FkOUcy5&index=20&t=481s)